# Simplified way to grab command line arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments

I just want to grab the command line arguments and send them to a file.

I've been doing a routine like:

```
echo ${1} ${2} ${3} ${4} >>filename
```

but really it should be done in a loop statement that I just can't seem to figure out as in

```
for x in {1..80}
do
   echo ${$x} >>filename
done
```

and of course that is incorrect.

Sorry to be so trivial...

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
echo "$@" >> filename
```